# How to set fixed height for mat-sidenav-content?

Tags: angular, angular-material

How to set fixed height for `<mat-sidenav-content>` or `<mat-sidenav-container>` as 100% of visible area?

Now content inside `<mat-sidenav-container></mat-sidenav-container>` dissapared when it has a lot of data.

```
<mat-sidenav-container><div class="content">A lot content here...</div></mat-sidenav-container>
```

My idea is to set:

```
.content {
    height: inherit;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

But now `<mat-sidenav-container>` has not height limit.

Comment: set `height:100vh` in `.content{}` css class

Comment: put one screen shot of prblem screen here.

Comment: It does not work

Comment: you have to set html, body to height to 100vh too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Set the height to 100vh

Which stands for viewport height.